# grails taglib namespace convention

Tags: grails

As my application is growing I am adding more and more tags and taglibs.  I have 8 taglibs, each with it's own related tags for a different part of the application.

To avoid conflict with grails tags or other plugin tags I've set a namespace.  Each taglib currently uses the same namespace.

```
static namespace = 'myapp'
```

It's easy so far for me to avoid conflict with my own tags, but I've got a new tag:

```
def each = { attrs, body ->
```

that I could see needing for different functionality elsewhere (each).  While I could do:

```
def thisTagLibNameEach = { attrs, body ->
```

or

```
static namespace = 'myappTagLibAAA'
```

is there a grails-y naming convention or way to avoid naming conflicts?

Comment: I'm not sure about the best practice aspects of this but I always use a different namespace for each taglib file. I usually use an acronym approach to reduce the namespace string size - e.g. "myapp utilities" = mau, "myapp numerics" - man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to make each TagLib to have it's own namespace, normally by functionality.

Also you can check the plugins that have installed, they maybe have TagLibs and you can avoid using the same namespace.